# TemplateDoesNotExist: account/register.html

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-registration

I am tryinging to create my own customized registration form. I already created register.html file in the templates folder, and I set the templates setting like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [Path(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
AUTH_USER_MODEL= "account.Account"
```

This is views.py for registration_view:

```
 from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from account.forms import RegistrationForm


def registration_view(request):
    context = {}
    if request.POST:
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            account = authenticate(email=email, password=raw_password)
            login(request, account)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            context['registration_form'] = form
    else: #GET request
        form = RegistrationForm()
        context['registration_form'] = form
    return render(request, 'account/register.html', context)
```

and this is my urls.py:

```
 from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

    from personal.views import (
    home_screen_view,
)

from account.views import (
    registration_view,
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home_screen_view, name="home"),
    path('register/', registration_view, name="register"),]
```

and this is the error I am getting

```
TemplateDoesNotExist: account/register.html
[21/May/2021 09:58:52] "GET /register/ HTTP/1.1" 500 73593
```

Can someone please tell me how can I solve this issue?

Comment: `templates/account/register.html` or `templates/register.html`? Try to stop the `runserver` command & start it again, Django has sometime difficulty noticing new files.

Comment: Yeap, still getting the same error

Comment: The file `register.html` should be in one of those folders (relative to your project): `templates/`, `account/templates/account/`, `personal/templates/account/`. These are the places that Django is looking for your files (for what I can infer from your code).

Comment: try changing `DIRS` in `settings.TEMPLATES` to an empty list, just checked one of my projects and it's like that.

Comment: Just tried, still the same error. @pongi yes it goes like account/templates/register.html

Comment: Try to either move the template file into `account/templates/account/register.html` (notice the repetition of `account`) or change the render invocation into `render(request, 'register.html', context)`.

Comment: Yes!! The first method worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

When you ask for a template with a certain path Django starts looking in a number of places:

- the paths specified in `DIRS` list;
- in all `templates` subdirectory of installed APPS (if `APP_DIRS` is `True`).

In the specific case, Django is asked to retrieve a template from `account/register.html` and tries these paths:

- `templates/account/register.html`
- `account/templates/account/register.html`
- `personal/templates/account/register.html`

You should either move the template file into `account/templates/account/register.html` (notice the repetition of account) or change the render invocation into `render(request, 'register.html', context)`.